# Dataset overwrites database table - Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure-data-factory

I was working on a data flow inside Azure Data Factory, I had a derived column section then a select column section and finally a sink section.

At the sink part I created a new dataset where my outcome should be stored and here comes my problem:
All the data from my table, inside my database, is completely gone! Reviewing everything I did I just can't find why. The only detail that calls my attention is the dataset settings. In the field "Table" I have the name of my database table. Is it possible that the dataset overwrited my data? If so how can I retrive it?
[Sink settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WvaMs.png)

Answer (score 0):

The image you shared are not the Sink settings, they are the Data Set settings. Data sets do not, in their own right, "do" anything, they merely define the connection. The Data Flow, however, could absolutely be responsible.

Open the Data Flow and highlight the Sink activity. Then open the "Settings" tab and check out the "Table action" options:
[image]

If "Recreate table" or "Truncate table" are selected, that would cause the behavior you are seeing.